# React Navigation have shared screens between conditions

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

```
<Stack.Navigator>
      {deliveryOutlet.deliveryAvailable === false ?
        <Stack.Group>

          <Stack.Screen
            name="NotDeliverable"
            component={NotDeliverable}
            options={{
              ...baseScreenOptions,
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="SelectAddress"
            component={SelectAddress}
            options={{
              ...baseScreenOptions,
            }}
          />
        </Stack.Group>
        :
<Stack.Group>

        <Stack.Screen
          name="BottomNavigator"
          component={BottomNavigator}
          options={{
            ...baseScreenOptions,
          }}
        />}
      <Stack.Screen
        name="OrderDetails"
        component={OrderDetails}
        options={{
          ...baseScreenOptions,
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="SelectAddress"
        component={SelectAddress}
        options={{
          ...baseScreenOptions,
        }}
      />
</Stack.Group>

    </Stack.Navigator>
```

I want to be able to forward to `SelectAddress` even if devlieryAvailable is true or false, doing like this gives me a duplicate screen name error, removing from any group makes it unavailable  under that condition

Answer (score 2):

You may follow the guide written in React-Naivgation document about  [Removing shared screens when auth state changes](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow#removing-shared-screens-when-auth-state-changes).

You can extract the common page `SelectAddress` from 2 Stack groups and put it under `<Stack.Navigator>`.

```
<Stack.Navigator>
  {deliveryOutlet.deliveryAvailable === false ?
    <>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="NotDeliverable"
        component={NotDeliverable}
        options={{
          ...baseScreenOptions,
        }}
      />
    </>
    :
    <>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="BottomNavigator"
        component={BottomNavigator}
        options={{
          ...baseScreenOptions,
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="OrderDetails"
        component={OrderDetails}
        options={{
          ...baseScreenOptions,
        }}
      />
    </>
  }
  
  <Stack.Screen
    name="SelectAddress"
    navigationKey={deliveryOutlet.deliveryAvailable === false ? 'notAvailable' : 'available'}
    component={SelectAddress}
    options={{
      ...baseScreenOptions,
    }}
  />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `a duplicate screen name error` because you put curly braces in the wrong place:

```js
<Stack.Navigator>
      {deliveryOutlet.deliveryAvailable === false ?
        <Stack.Group>

          <Stack.Screen
            name="NotDeliverable"
            component={NotDeliverable}
            options={{
              ...baseScreenOptions,
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="SelectAddress"
            component={SelectAddress}
            options={{
              ...baseScreenOptions,
            }}
          />
        </Stack.Group>
        :
<Stack.Group>

        <Stack.Screen
          name="BottomNavigator"
          component={BottomNavigator}
          options={{
            ...baseScreenOptions,
          }}
        />} // <== wrong curly braces
      <Stack.Screen
        name="OrderDetails"
        component={OrderDetails}
        options={{
          ...baseScreenOptions,
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="SelectAddress"
        component={SelectAddress}
        options={{
          ...baseScreenOptions,
        }}
      />
</Stack.Group>

    </Stack.Navigator>
```

Correct code:

```js
<Stack.Navigator>
  {deliveryOutlet.deliveryAvailable === false ? (
    <Stack.Group>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="NotDeliverable"
        component={NotDeliverable}
        options={{
          ...baseScreenOptions,
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="SelectAddress"
        component={SelectAddress}
        options={{
          ...baseScreenOptions,
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Group>
  ) : (
    <Stack.Group>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="BottomNavigator"
        component={BottomNavigator}
        options={{
          ...baseScreenOptions,
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="OrderDetails"
        component={OrderDetails}
        options={{
          ...baseScreenOptions,
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="SelectAddress"
        component={SelectAddress}
        options={{
          ...baseScreenOptions,
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Group>
  )}
</Stack.Navigator>
```